# unable to upgrade kernel - 'dpkg: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured' and '(dkms apport): kernel package linux-*** is not supported'

Tags: upgrade, kernel, dpkg

Currently, my kernel version is: 6.4.10-060410-generic and I'm using Ubuntu 23.04. When I was trying to upgrade my kernel suddenly I got an error. I get this error not only for version 6.5.1 but also when I want to upgrade to any version.

Also, while I was able to update with mainline without any errors before, I started getting such errors after I wanted to install version 6.5.0 and I cannot update to any version.

```
mainline 1.4.8
install 6.5.1 
Downloading 6.5.1
Installing 6.5.1                                                      
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-6.5.1-060501-generic.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-image-unsigned-6.4.10-060410-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 215872 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-6.5.1-060501-generic_6.5.1-060501.202309020842_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-6.5.1-060501-generic (6.5.1-060501.202309020842) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-6.5.1-060501-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-6.5.1-060501-generic_6.5.1-060501.202309020842_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-6.5.1-060501-generic (6.5.1-060501.202309020842) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-6.5.1-060501_6.5.1-060501.202309020842_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-6.5.1-060501 (6.5.1-060501.202309020842) over (6.5.1-060501.202309020842) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-unsigned-6.5.1-060501-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-unsigned-6.5.1-060501-generic_6.5.1-060501.202309020842_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-unsigned-6.5.1-060501-generic (6.5.1-060501.202309020842) ...
Setting up linux-modules-6.5.1-060501-generic (6.5.1-060501.202309020842) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-6.5.1-060501-generic:
 linux-headers-6.5.1-060501-generic depends on libc6 (>= 2.38); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.37-0ubuntu2.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.5.1-060501-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-headers-6.5.1-060501 (6.5.1-060501.202309020842) ...
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-6.5.1-060501-generic (6.5.1-060501.202309020842) ...
I: /boot/vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to vmlinuz-6.4.14-060414-generic
I: /boot/vmlinuz is now a symlink to vmlinuz-6.5.1-060501-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-6.5.1-060501-generic
Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-6.5.1-060501-generic (6.5.1-060501.202309020842) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.1-060501-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
unset ARCH; [ ! -h /usr/bin/cc ] && export CC=/usr/bin/gcc; env NV_VERBOSE=1 'make' -j16 NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=6.5.1-060501-generic IGNORE_XEN_PRESENCE=1 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 SYSSRC=/lib/modules/6.5.1-060501-generic/build LD=/usr/bin/ld.bfd CONFIG_X86_KERNEL_IBT= modules....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-6.5.1-060501-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.1-060501-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.125.06/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.1-060501-generic/x86_64 failed for nvidia(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.5.1-060501-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-unsigned-6.5.1-060501-generic (--install):
 installed linux-image-unsigned-6.5.1-060501-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.5.1-060501-generic
 linux-image-unsigned-6.5.1-060501-generic
mainline: done
```

Comment: `/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.125.06/build/make.log` will have more info. Though most likely it would be because of newer version of `libc6` as mentioned by Alexey Panzer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I have to downgrade the kernel to previous stable 6.4.10 version, also I removed installed 6.5.0. The reason is different libc6 versions.

I recommend you to wait the new stable libc6 version.

OR

You have to compile the kernel by yourself to be able to install it (very risky for non pro users).

Comment: Yes, while trying to upgrade to version 6.5, I saw the libc incompatibility in the error at first, but it gives the same error when upgrading to version 6.4.14(stable).

Answer (score 0):

I found this article discussing this problem [link text](https://9to5linux.com/you-can-now-install-linux-kernel-6-5-on-ubuntu-heres-how). I have studied on kernel and system upgrades and found that timing of open source software and other software releases are key. Namely GPU drivers and Operating Systems. For example when a system upgrade is available, a GPU proprietary driver may not yet be available for that version. Which could cause problems or degrade, and can be a challenge to recover. Always make backups before these major upgrades.